# How to achieve rolling restart with systemd?

Tags: deployment, systemd

I have 2 servers started as independent systemd units. They are listening on port 3001 and 3002 respectively.

I want to achieve a rolling restart (also known as rolling update or ramped update, [more info on this deployment strategy](https://thenewstack.io/deployment-strategies/)).

Here is the sequence of event I am looking for when running 'systemctl restart app':

1. app-unit1 running && app-unit2 running
2. app-unit1 stopped
3. app-unit1 started
4. app-unit2 stopped
5. app-unit2 started

By doing so, with my loadbalancer in front of these servers, I can reload these servers without interrupting the global service.

I implemented the configuration described in [this article](http://alesnosek.com/blog/2016/12/04/controlling-a-multi-service-application-with-systemd/):

/etc/systemd/system/app.service

```
[Unit]
Description=app
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/etc/systemd/system/app-unit1.service

```
[Unit]
Description=app-unit1
PartOf=app.service
After=app.service

[Service]
Type=notify

Environment=PORT=3001
ExecStart=/usr/bin/start-server.sh
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=app.service
```

/etc/systemd/system/app-unit2.service

```
[Unit]
Description=app-unit2
PartOf=app.service
After=app.service
After=app-unit1.service

[Service]
Type=notify

Environment=PORT=3002
ExecStart=/usr/bin/start-server.sh
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=app.service
```

The resulting sequence of event when running 'systemctl restart app':

1. app-unit1 running && app-unit2 running
2. app-unit2 stopped && app-unit1 stopped (not sure which one is stopped first)
3. app-unit1 started
4. app-unit2 started

So, I have an interruption of service between step 2 and step 3.

The question is: how to achieve rolling restart with systemd ?

Comment: `Type=notify` requires a systemd-aware daemon, not a shell script.

Comment: did you figure out how to do this?

Comment: Nope. I had to use another process manager for my nodejs processes : PM2.